# How to fill columns of Forms.ListViewItem with desired ordering?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm adding data to a `System.Windows.ListViewItem.Subitems` collection which is a `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection` data type. I know there is no order associated with items added to a collection of data. Thus, filling a collection with data in an arbitrary order has no effect on your data store. (Edit: I now know that collections are not the same as sets where data is unordered).

How do I control which column each data in my collection is assigned/displayed? As of right now, my data is being displayed, however, it seems to be arbitrarily assigned.

There is some order to how the data is being displayed but it jumps around a little...

```
public LogMessageItem ( LoggerItem parent, LogMessage logMsg )
{
    Parent = parent;
    Message = logMsg;
    string parentName = Parent.Name;

    if( (Parent.Name == logMsg.ThreadName) && (Parent.Parent != null) )
        parentName = Parent.Parent.Name;

    Item                 = new ListViewItem ( logMsg.TimeStamp.ToString ( UserSettings.Instance.TimeStampFormatString ) );   // Create List View Item
    Item.SubItems.Add    ( logMsg.Level.Name );    // Appears in column 0
    Item.SubItems.Add    ( parentName );           // value is null
    Item.SubItems.Add    ( logMsg.ThreadName );    // Appears in column 6

    string  msg          = logMsg.Message.Replace ( "\r\n", " " );
    msg                  = msg.Replace ( "\n", " " );
    Item.SubItems.Add    ( msg );                  // Appears in column 7
    Item.ToolTipText     = msg;

    Item.ForeColor       = logMsg.Level.Color;
    Item.Tag             = this;
}
```

Perhaps there is a preferred ordering to how data is entered based on how the column header is initialized?

The data in the above example is being displayed properly however when I edit this, I want the columns 8 and on to be filled. The existing columns 0 through 7 are being displayed correctly until I make edits to this code after the line that contains `Item.Tag = this;`. What it does is begins adding data to columns 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column order of the sub-items is simply determined by the order in which you add the new sub-item.

Calling `Add` on the `ListViewSubItemCollection` would add them at the position indicated:

- "Sub-item 1" -> Column 2
- "Sub-item 2" -> Column 3
- And so on

You can insert an item to a specific position using the `Insert` method of the `ListViewSubItemCollection`, however, this will move "up" the existing items and place the new item at the specified `index`.

You can modify the "columns" (or more correctly, sub-items) at will after they have been added but they must be added first.

**Edit following user comment**

In order to achieve 8 columns in the `ListView`, you simply need to add 7 sub-items (the first column is always the `Text` of the `ListViewItem`) as so

```
ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem("Column 1");

newItem.SubItems.Add("Column 2");
newItem.SubItems.Add("Column 3");
newItem.SubItems.Add("Column 4");
newItem.SubItems.Add("Column 5");
newItem.SubItems.Add("Column 6");
newItem.SubItems.Add("Column 7");
newItem.SubItems.Add("Column 8");
```

You can replace the names I have put (i.e. "Column 6") with whatever is required - including an empty string `""` which will show as an empty value in that column.

Once you have added the sub-items they can be changed at will, but they *must* be added first by doing the above.
It is perfectly normal just to add the correct value into each sub-item (column) as you add them.

However, if you wanted to modify the sub-item\column after you have added it, simply do the following:

```
newItem.SubItems[0].Text = "New column 2 value";
newItem.SubItems[1].Text = "New column 3 value";
```

The `SubItems` collection is zero-based (as usual), so a value of 0 will mean column 2, a value of 1 will mean column 3 and so on.
To change column 1 just modify the `Text` property of the `ListViewItem` itself:

```
newItem.Text = "New column 1 value";
```

Comment: The first 3 columns have data already, the following 3 don't (which I plan to leave alone) and the following 2 also have data. Meaning columns, 0, 1, 2, 6, and 7 have data. If I use the `Insert` method it fails with an `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. I'd like to `Add` or `Insert` add column index 8+ but since I have empty columns prior to that index (somehow initialized elsewhere) it gives me that unhandled exception.

Comment: @AlexSmith I have updated the question to provide more detail in order to address your query more fully.